# How to count number of rows in sencha gridview?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a Gridview on my page and I'm using buffered store. Is there a way to get the visible number of row count. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that you can try: (I hope you'll get some idea from this)

```
// The below condition has to be checked for each record
// record: record instance
var me = this; // grid scope
Ext.Array.each(me.columns, function (item) { // iterate through each column in the grid
    if (item.hidden || !item.dataIndex) { // you can avoid hidden columns and one's that re not bound to the store
        return;
    }
    var cellVal;
    try {
        cellVal = Ext.fly( me.view.getCell(record, item)).select('cell selector class').elements[0].innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        // handle if you want
    }
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(cellVal)) {
        // this record has been rendered
    }

}, this);
```

*This will get you all the records that are rendered. Since you are using a bufferedRenderer, this will also return the records that are rendered but not in the view, you can check and put an offset for the buffer.*

Note: I've a similar logic in working in ExtJs 5 but haven't tested in touch.

Comment: Ext.fly( me.view.getCell(record, item)).select('cell selector class') return the right value only if the record has been rendered. So, just make sure that you call it after the grid has been rendered.